# Finding highest selling item within a category

Tags: google-sheets, max, google-sheets-formula, maxifs

I am looking to find the highest selling drink within each category in cells C6:C16.  I am able to find the highest value in each category with a MAXIFS function, but I want to further pull the corresponding beverage name (for example, Stella Artois for the Beer Category).  How do I find that value?  Is it a VLOOKUP?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **This can be done in multiple ways:**

You can expand the formula in column C and use `VLOOKUP` to get the highest selling item per category:

`=VLOOKUP(MAXIFS($C$20:$C$200,$A$20:$A$200,A6),FILTER({$C$20:$C$200,$A$20:$B$200},$A$20:$A$200=A6),3)`

Or if you want to reference column C, you can reduce to this:

`=VLOOKUP(C6,FILTER({$C$20:$C$200,$A$20:$B$200},$A$20:$A$200=A6),3)`

**Output:**

[image]

**Caveat:**

Note that this needs autofill / dragging down to C16 to get all the needed values.

Comment: Thank you!!  This is great.  I used the first formula provided and added FALSE to the end and was able to get what I needed.